# how to pass 2 Domain obects to 1 jsp page via controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

guys i need your help,

please tell me how can i pass 2 different domain object in 1 jsp page via one spring controller.

and also tell how can i retrieve it,

let i have 2 class having atleast 2 fields

i think i have to use a MAP(key,value)

but how can i use it in jsp

how can i call the different object that are stored in the values ok map.

please guide me friends

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just put your two objects under different keys in your `Model` / `ModelAndView` / `Map` / ..:

```
@RequestMapping(..)
public String controllerMethod(..., Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("object1", foo);
    model.addAttribute("object2", bar);
}
```

in the JSP:

```
${object1.something}
${object2.anotherThing}
```